# Mutate in dplyr the proportions of TRUE or FALSE in 2 new columns

Tags: r, dplyr, percentage

I have the following table in R:

| CAT | CONDITION |
| --- | --- |
| A | TRUE |
| A | TRUE |
| A | FALSE |
| A | TRUE |
| B | TRUE |
| B | TRUE |
| B | TRUE |
| B | FALSE |

```
cat = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4));cat
cond = c("TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE")
data3 = cbind(cat,cond);data3
```

and i want to reduce it in dplyr giving me the (mutating two new columns) with the percentages of TRUE in the first new column and the percentages of FALSE in the second new column.Like this :

| CAT | TRUE | FALSE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.5 | 0.5 |
| B | 0.75 | 0.25 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also simply use `mean` with `logical` variables:

```
library(dplyr)
data3 %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% # this converts your matrix into a tibble
        mutate(cond = as.logical(cond)) %>% # convert character to logical
        group_by(cat) %>% 
        summarise("TRUE" = mean(cond),
                  "FALSE" = mean(!cond))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  cat   `TRUE` `FALSE`
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A       0.75    0.25
2 B       0.5     0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside `dplyr`, this is made really easy with `prop.table` and `table`:

```r
with(as.data.frame(data3), prop.table(table(cat, cond), 1))

   cond
cat FALSE TRUE
  A  0.25 0.75
  B  0.50 0.50
```

---

Or, even simpler (credits to @G. Grothendieck), using `xtabs`:

```r
prop.table(xtabs(~., data3), 1)
```

Comment: Also `prop.table(xtabs(~., data3), 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
cat = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4))
cond = c("TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE")
data3 = data.frame(cat,cond)

data3 %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  summarise("TRUE" = sum(cond == TRUE) / n(),
            "FALSE" = sum(cond == FALSE) / n())
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   cat   `TRUE` `FALSE`
#>   <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.75    0.25
#> 2 B       0.5     0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes yes i mixed up in a wrong way the true and falses.Yes this is what i want.Thanks you very much for the clear answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way: If you want to get the proportions of `TRUE` `FALSE` for each `CAT` then this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(CAT, CONDITION) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  mutate(n = (n/sum(n))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = CAT,
    names_from = CONDITION,
    values_from = n
  )
```

```
  CAT   `FALSE` `TRUE`
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A        0.25   0.75
2 B        0.25   0.75
```